# Evaluating return value of bash function as integer

Tags: bash, function, testing, comparison, return

I've been trying to write a bash function to check if a variable is an integer.  The is_number function in the script below does this check.

When I run it though (with a test value of 1234) I get the following error message:

```
./test_n2.sh: line 13: [: Checking 1234
1234: integer expression expected
n is not an integrer
```

I'm confused: the function returns $?, which in my one liner tests with grep is correctly set to 0 for integral values.  The integer comparison in the main block is done as [ "$retval" -eq 0 ], which AFAIK is the correct form for testing integers.

Can someone please help?

### TIA.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function is_number {
    number=$1
    echo "Checking $number"
    echo $number | /bin/egrep '^[0-9]+$'    
    return $?
}

n=1234
retval=`is_number $n`

if [ "$retval" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo n is an integer
    exit 0
fi

echo n is not an integrer
exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

When you assign a variable using backticks or `$(...)`, it gets the standard output of the command. The return value of a command is put in the variable `$?`. So you should do:

```
is_number $n
retval=$?
```

Or you can simply write:

```
if is_number $n; then
    echo n is an integer
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and not I feel truly foolish for overlooking the fact that backticks channel the standard output and not the return value.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `grep` for this at all, bash on its own will happily do the job, and more efficiently:

```
is_number() {
    # Check if $1 only consists of digits
    [[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
if is_number 123; then
    echo "it's a number!"
else
    echo "it's not a number!"
fi
```

Use this with the following caveat: if you need to perform arithmetic, be aware that leading zero's will force bash to interpret the string as a number in radix 8. Hence the following is an error:

```
a=09
if is_number "$a"; then
    echo $((a+1));
else
    echo "Not a number"
fi
```

Your snippet is hence better written as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
is_number() {
    # Check if $1 only consists of digits
    [[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]
}

n=1234
if is_number "$n"; then
    echo "n is an integer"
    exit 0
else
    echo "n is not an integer"
    exit 1
fi
```

or if you need to save the return value of the function `is_number`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
is_number() {
    # Check if $1 only consists of digits
    [[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]
}

n=1234
is_number "$n"
ret=$?
if ((ret==0)); then
    echo "n is an integer"
else
    echo "n is not an integer"
fi

exit "$ret"
```